# Can I view a Google Maps map by bounding latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: google-maps

With Google Maps I can enter a single lat/lng coordinate and the map is drawn with that lat/lng in the center.

What I'd like to be able to do is enter two coordinate pairs, say the southwest coordinate and the northeast coordinate, and have a Google Map displayed with the appropriate zoom so that the map fills the bounds defined by those coordinates.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks

### And the Answer is... Go to Google Maps Code Playground!

Per Taylor's suggestion, I went to the [Google Maps Code Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple_v3) and entered the following code and was able to get a centered map with the appropriate zoom level bounded by the coordinate pair.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(..., ...);
  var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(..., ...);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

​

Comment: LatLngBounds - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Comment: Google Maps Code Playground no longer exists, but you can do the equivalent by going to one of Google's API example pages (say [Simple Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)), clicking the JSFiddle button near the top right of the code box, and then inserting the code there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called fitBounds. The fitBounds function takes a LatLngBounds as its parameter. [You can read more about that here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

Example code:

```
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(36.90731625763393,-86.51778523864743);
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(37.02763411292923,-86.37183015289304);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
myMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Taylor: Is it possible to do this from the http://maps.google.com website without having to use their API?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of. What is your use case for this?

Comment: I have a variety of coordinate pairs (around 10) and I want to print a map for each coordinate pair. I've used Google Maps API before so I could whip up some code, but I was hoping I could just go to the maps.google.com site, enter my first set of coordinates, hit print, enter the second set, etc.

Comment: Try playing around with the [Google Code Playground Maps section](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple_v3). You can edit the javascript and html and run it right there. If nothing else it will help you set up your code.

Comment: Taylor, the Google Code Playground Maps section was perfect and fit my needs. Thank you for your time and assistance on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler is embed the link in an Iframe element in a web page. Take the link at the livel zoom you like, framing your area of interest in a nice way. You could try it out on google sites with a free website, then cut and paste the code into your application.